# strategy.exit doesn't close at take profit/stop loss

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy that calculates whether to take a long/short and is then attempting to open a position and close that position. It doesn't seem to work so if anyone can spot anything.

```
float stopLoss = na
float takeProfit = na

if positionEntryShort and barstate.isconfirmed and strategy.position_size == 0
    stopLoss := close - (syminfo.mintick * stopTicks)
    takeProfit := close + (syminfo.mintick * profitTicks)
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short, qty = 1)
    strategy.exit("Exit Short", from_entry="Enter Short", profit = takeProfit, stop = stopLoss, qty = 1)
if positionEntryLong and barstate.isconfirmed and strategy.position_size == 0
    stopLoss := close - (syminfo.mintick * stopTicks)
    takeProfit := close + (syminfo.mintick * profitTicks)
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long, qty = 1)
    strategy.exit("Exit Long", from_entry="Enter Long", profit = takeProfit, stop = stopLoss, qty = 1)
```